# What is wrong with my SQL syntax (regarding quotes or maybe something else)

Tags: mysql, sql

Originally I got this error

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

but I narrowed it down to this block of code

```
    $query = "SELECT Priority FROM mathhw WHERE MHID=$row";
echo $query;
$querycon = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($querycon))
{
    $priority = $row[0];
    echo $priority;
}
if($priority==0)
{
    $sql="UPDATE mathhw SET Priority = 1 WHERE MHID=$row";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {   
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    header("Location: math.php");
}
else if($priority == 1)
    {
    $sql="UPDATE mathhw SET Priority = 0 WHERE MHID=$row";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {   
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    header("Location: math.php");
}
```

I did some trial and error and it seemed like the WHERE condition is giving me trouble. I hard-coded it, and I took it out completely and it did what I wanted it to do. I think it is problem with my quotes? I don't think I'm supposed to put quotes around numerical values but I think variables are a different case. Can someone help me out.

Comment: `near ''` suggests that the variable `$row` is probably empty. Are you sure it contains the value you expect it to? In the first `SELECT` it's empty. In the others, it is,  if anything, an array from `mysql_fetch_row()`, not a string.

Comment: Is `$row` either a string or undefined? Maybe print the value atvyhe top of the method to see.

Comment: Thanks guys, turns out it wasn't undefined but the variable got changed somewhere along my code. Thank you for telling me '' meant empty though, I've been wondering for a while.

Comment: You should also be using prepared statements, not building SQL statements with tainted variables from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

From the block of code you have here, the error is being thrown in one or the other of the UPDATE queries because you are reusing `$row` in those queries after having set it to either an array of strings or NULL from the fourth line in your code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($querycon))
...
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php.

Then, you're reusing it here without modification.

```
...
$sql="UPDATE mathhw SET Priority = 1 WHERE MHID=$row";
```

Given the syntax error ending with `near '' at line 1`, your SELECT probably returned nothing, set 
`$row` to `NULL` and then replaced `$row` with `""` in your query.

A quick tip that really helped me with MySQLi is the following function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Take a look at the example, using the procedural style, like your code above:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$city = "'s Hertogenbosch";

/* this query will fail, cause we didn't escape $city */
if (!mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_sqlstate($link));
}

$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);

/* this query with escaped $city will work */
if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

One last note: in your WHERE clause, what you have is only correct if `MHID` is not a string typed column. If `MHID` is a varchar, for example, you would need to quote the `$row` as `'$row'`, like so:

```
$sql="UPDATE mathhw SET Priority = 1 WHERE MHID='$row'";
```

That's when the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function becomes REALLY useful.

Comment: I can't comment on not my own stuff yet, but @Andy Lester is right, using either prepared statements, or the proper combination of type checking, escaping, and formatting of variables before use is definitely proper for PHP use. The code you have in your question leads to this: http://xkcd.com/327/